# Calculate certain points in a range

Tags: loops, range

Given the range of numbers `[20-80]` and a certain number of points say `5`

How can i calculate those points in that range with `20` being the first and `80` being the last, which leaves 3 points in between and the distance should be even.

Answer (score 0):

`x(i)=xmin+(xmax-xmin)*i/(num-1)`, where `xmin` and `xmax` are the bounds and `num` is the number of points you need, (and then `i = 0 ... (num-1)`).
JavaScript code with `20-80`, and `5` points:

```js
var xmin=20;
var xmax=80;
var num=5;
for(var i=0;i<num;i++)
  console.log(xmin+(xmax-xmin)*i/(num-1));
```